# Weather data: mean or median?

Tags: r, mean, validation, median

I downloaded TRMM data in order to get the precipitation value in certain locations, these location correspond to my gauge positions. My current goal is to compare those single-pixel and gauge values monthly and I've been using boxplots in order to get a first glance evaluation.

My doubt is, for example, for February the mean and median TRMM value are 140.1 and 132.6mm and the gauge mean and median values are 103.5 and 99.3mm. In order to get a representative value of the month in each dataset which should I use, mean or median?

Comment: It depends on what you are trying to "validate."  Your question really cannot be objectively answered using the little information you have provided, but if you could explain your objectives it might be possible to make some progress.

Comment: @whuber I appreciate your comment. I downloaded precipitation data in order to get the precipitation value in certain locations, these locations correspond to my gauge positions. My current goal is to compare those single-pixel values and gauge values monthly. I've been using boxplots in order to get a first glance evaluation. My doubt is, for example, for February the mean and median TRMM values are 140.1 and 132.6mm and the gauge mean and median values are 103.5 and 99.3mm. In order to get a representative value of the month in each dataset which should I use, mean or median? Thank you

Comment: Could you explain how you intend to use these "representative values"?  In a validation or calibration context one would not proceed to compare averages, but instead would compare actual values to actual values, gauge by gauge.

Comment: @whuber I want to know how much difference there is between gauge data and TRMM data in my time series (18 years of data). If I use the mean value I am overestimating the rain and if I use the median I am underestimate rain (according to the example above). Since I have to state a single value to represent the monthly rain this value is very important.

Comment: Do you have sets of values, or just a mean & median for each month / location? Are you trying to assess the agreement between your personal data & some official recordings to see if yours are systematically low, or something like that?

Comment: @gung Not, yet (I'm working on it) but I'm going to evaluate the difference with some other statistic and non statistics parameters [see this]{https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B7mw858dxh5MM040eTJLdzR5WUJ3SjgzRUZaZWhzQjZoOFNF} but I need a first statistical evaluation to start with. And yes, I'm trying to assess the agreement between official recordings (gauge data) and satellite data (TRMM) and see how much difference there is (a quantitative difference).